# tweepy stream.filter() method doesn't work properly

Tags: python, twitter, filter, stream, tweepy

i've got some problems with the tweepy api.

I'm just tryin to write a little app that gets me a stream of statuses of one user (ore more), but one would be fine to start with ;-)

now: my code is like that:

```
    def main():
       config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
       config.read('twitter.cfg')

       username = config.get('Twitter', 'username')
       password = config.get('Twitter', 'password') 
           listener = StreamWatcherListener()

       stream = tweepy.Stream(username, password, listener, timeout=None)
       stream.filter('132897940')
```

in StreamWatcherListener I have a method "on_status" that prints the text of a status, whenever a new one arrives (everything seems to work, when I try stream.sample() instead of stream.filter())

the given ID is my testaccount, so whenever I tweet I should get some response in the console....but nothing happens.

when I try

```
curl -d @following http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -uAnyTwitterUser:Password
```

in the terminal as I could find in the twitter api, everything runs fine.

So maybe I make wrong use of the filter()-method?

any suggestions?

-andy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it out myself

the `stream.filter()` method needs an array

so i had to code

```
stream.filter(['1234567'])
```

et voilà

Answer (score 0):

```
class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self,status):           
        print "TWEET ARRIVED!!!"
        print "Tweet Text : %s" % status.text
        print "Author's name : %s" % status.author.screen_name
        print "Time of creation : %s" % status.created_at
        print "Source of Tweet : %s" % status.source    
        time.sleep(10)       
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):        
       print status
       if status == 420:
            print "Too soon reconnected, Exiting!!"
            return False
        sys.exit()

def search_tweets():
    twitterStream = Stream(connect().auth, TweetListener())        
    twitterStream.filter(track=['Cricket','Maths','Army','Sports'],languages = ["en"],async=True)
```

Here I used the async parameter, it runs each stream on a different thread.
Refer this  [link](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html)  for documentation or more details.

Comment: Hey, I want to get tweets from a specific user "X" with a specific text "Y"....But I cant make that work. Either it gives me all tweets from X or it gives me all tweets containing Y. How does it work?