# Follow user in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking to follow users that follow me, but I don't already follow in Tweepy. I've got the logic, but my issue is the syntax.

```
    for follower in followers_list:
        if follower not in friends_list:
            to_follow.append(follower)  
            print to_follow
    for follower in to_follow:
       print follower
       api.follow(follower)
```

Does anyone know what I should use to follow people (in place of the api.follow, which doesn't work)

Comment: create_friendship is what I'm looking for, however, it says I need to be authenticated. Anyone know of I way I can use create_friendship while using arrays with my people to follow?

Comment: A non-related suggestion: your fist loop may be replaced by a [list comprehenstion](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `to_follow = [follower for follower in followers_list if follower not in friends_list]`. I know it does not solve your question, but I think it can be your code a bit more pythonic :)

Answer (score 4):

Is your followers_list filled with Twitter user.screen_names?  If so, there's a topic on the issue that should help you out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646295/tweepy-stream-filter-method-doesnt-work-properly).

The followers_list should be inside a comma-separated list, like the following:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, StreamWatcherListener(), timeout=None)
follow_list = ['1234567890', '2345678901']
track_list = None
stream.filter(follow_list, track_list)
```